Classic Scholars Opinion On Ibadi Sect
Did The scholars of Ahl Sunnah Wal Jammah consider Ibadi's even kaffir or they differed over it?

The Ibadi sect is a branch of the Khawarij. The scholars of the Ahl al-Sunnah differ on whether the Khawarij should be declared and treated as disbelievers.
The majority opinion is that they are not. The reason is that most of the Sahaba did not declare them to be disbelievers and did not apply the rulings of disbelievers or apostates on them - for example they did not enslave them or their families, nor did they distribute their property as spoils of war.

لما قتل علي رضي الله عنه الحرورية , قالوا: من هؤلاء يا أمير المؤمنين أكفار هم؟ قال: من الكفر فروا
When Ali had fought the Haruriyyah (group of the Khawarij) he was asked: "O leader of the believers are these people disbelievers?"
Ali said: "Rather they fled from disbelief."
— Musannaf Ibn Abi Shaybah and  Musannaf Abdul Razzaq

The second opinion is that they are disbelievers. Evidence for this is cited from the ahadith which are understood to be about the Khawarij who were fought by the sahaba:

يخرج فيكم قوم تحقرون صلاتكم مع صلاتهم، وصيامكم مع صيامهم، وعملكم مع عملهم، ويقرءون القرآن لا يجاوز حناجرهم، يمرقون من الدين كما يمرق السهم من الرمية، ينظر في النصل فلا يرى شيئا، وينظر في القدح فلا يرى شيئا، وينظر في الريش فلا يرى شيئا، ويتمارى في الفوق
There will appear some people among you whose prayer will make you look down upon yours, and whose fasting will make you look down upon yours, but they will recite the Qur'an which will not exceed their throats (they will not act on it) and they will go out of Islam as an arrow goes out through the game whereupon the archer would examine the arrowhead but see nothing, and look at the unfeathered arrow but see nothing, and look at the arrow feathers but see nothing, and finally he suspects to find something in the lower part of the arrow.
— Bukhari


فأينما لقيتموهم فاقتلوهم، فإن في قتلهم أجرا لمن قتلهم يوم القيامة
So, wherever you find them, kill them, for whoever kills them shall have reward on the Day of Resurrection.
— Bukhari


هم شر الخلق
They would be the worst among the creation
— Muslim


لئن أدركتهم لأقتلنهم قتل ثمود
If I should be present at their time I would kill them as the nations of Thamud were killed.
— Bukhari


عن أبي أمامة، يقول شر قتلى قتلوا تحت أديم السماء وخير قتلى من قتلوا كلاب أهل النار قد كان هؤلاء مسلمين فصاروا كفارا ‏.‏ قلت يا أبا أمامة هذا شىء تقوله قال بل سمعته من رسول الله ـ صلى الله عليه وسلم
Abu Umamah said:
"(The Khawarij) are the worst of the slain who are killed under heaven, and the best of the slain are those who were killed by them. Those (Khawarij) are the dogs of Hell. Those people were Muslims but they became disbelievers."
I said: "O Abu Umamah, is that your opinion?"
He said: "Rather I heard it from the Messenger of Allah ﷺ."
— Ibn Majah and  Jami at-Tirmidhi

The apparent meaning of the ahadith is that they are disbelievers:

Because the hadith states that they 'go out of Islam' which is kufr. The analogy used implies that they have left it completely and have absolutely no faith.

Because of the exhortation and reward of killing them.

Because to be the worst of creation they have to be among disbelievers and not better than them. See  Quran 8:55, Quran 6:21 etc.

Because they are compared to Aad and Thamud who were disbelievers.


Ref:

وأكثر الفقهاء يرون أنهم بغاة، ولا يرون تكفيرهم، وذهبت طائفة من أهل الحديث إلى أنهم كفار مرتدون
— Mawsoo’ah al-Fiqhiyyah


going out of Islam, means they will go against tenets of Islam, like creating mischief in the world ( like torturing people, forcing religion upon others etc), like what some so called Muslims do today.

@Shafeek Torturing people, creating mischief, forcing religion upon others are all major sins but they aren't related to the "tenets" of Islam and doing so will make you a fasiq for sure but not take you out of the fold of Islam. Getting out of the fold of Islam is largely based on beliefs not actions.

@SyedM.Sannan "And whoever opposes the Messenger after guidance has become clear to him and follows other than the way of the believers - We will give him what he has taken and drive him into Hell, and evil it is as a destination." Quran 4:115. So if you follow ways other that of Muslims, like forcing religion upon others , causing mischief in the world etc. this is Quran's warning. of course the door of Thawba (repentance) is always open.

@Shafeek Be clearer, please. Are you saying that causing mischief and forcing religion upon people takes you out of the fold of Islam? Give me a yes or no answer, no other thing. The verse you referenced does not explicitly say that, you are only using it for your interpretation.

Ultimate judge is Allah. I think those who create mischief in the world should be more careful, I just quoted one Ayah, those who read this ayah should take care about themselves. One thing I am sure is forcing belief on others and creating mischief is not believers way. (Quran 2:256 , Quran 10:99 )
